# Sum/Effects contrast coding in R: What would be the default reference level for a three level sum-coded variable?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, categorical-data

I was using [this](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-how-do-i-interpret-the-coefficients-of-an-effect-coded-variable-involved-in-an-interaction-in-a-regression-model/#effect-coding-for-categorical-predictors-with-3-or-more-levels) tutorial to understand how coefficients must be interpreted after effect-coding variables. If I had a two-level variable called Gender, like so:

```
levels(data$gender)
[1] "F" "M"
```

then with a two-level effect-coded predictor, R would choose the last level as the reference level, such that M would be considered the reference level.
What would happen if I had a three-level variable, as in:

```
levels(data$gender)
[1] "F" "M" "T"
```

What the tutorial would translate to in my example here is that if I specify that this should be effect-coded in R, then R will use T as the reference level/contrasting group, and give me two effect-coded regressors Gender1 and Gender2 in the regression table.

If T is now the reference level, and this is the regression table:

|  | Estimate | SE | z-value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | -0.93189 | 0.54697 | -1.704 |
| Gender1 | 0.25600 | 0.48660 | 0.526 |
| Gender2 | 0.03362 | 0.35100 | 0.096 |

then would the coefficient for Gender1 be the coefficient of F when compared to the grand mean? And Gender2 that of M against the grand mean?

Thank you for your time.

Edit: this is just a random example I came up with, but say I'm looking at the effect of gender of subjects on whether or not they're admitted into a tough school. Outcome variable would be binary. The regression table is again, just random numbers from a random regression table from my work. I just want to know how this works, and don't really have a specific example.

Comment: What is your outcome variable? Could you supply the code you wrote for obtaining the estimates?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I've edited my question with your recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking at `logistic regression`. In that case you are estimating `odds` and not the mean.

The interpretation of your table is that the odds of your estimate in the reference group is `exp(-0.93189)`.

`Gender 1` has `exp(0.25600)` higher odds, while `Gender 2` has `exp(0.03362)`. It is difficult to translate that to `F`, `M` and `T` as the covariates included in your regression table is labeled `Gender 1` and `Gender 2`.

You can change the reference of your factors like this:

`data$gender <- relevel(gender, ref = "T")` - in case you want `data$gender == T` as reference.

Comment: This is my bad but I should have given more info. I've edited it again.